# number followed by capital L

Tags: c, xv6

What does `512L` mean? (or probably any number followed by capital L)

example:

`uint sec`
and then some code with the expression:
`sec * 512L`

(taken out of the [XV6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xv6) code - mkfs.c)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`L` stands for **l**ong.

This creates a literal of type `long`.

`l` would also work, but it looks like `1`, so it should be avoided.

Comment: @ReutSharabani Really? google "C integer literals" gets right there.