# I can't understand what a fseek parameter does

Tags: c

I need a binary file with read-only privilege to understand the output of a code snippet, but I don't know how to create a binary so I tried to simulate it on paper, but I don't understand one little part. Here is the code:

```
FILE *fp;
char buf[256];
fp=fopen("test.dat", "rb");
fread(buf, 5, 4, fp);
fseek(fp, -5L, SEEK_CUR);
printf("%d", ftell (fp));
```

What does -5L mean? I know "-value" on fseek means that the pointer will move "value" positions ahead of SEEK_CUR(current position), but I don't know what -5L is equal to.

Comment: [Does `fseek`documentation help](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek) ?

Comment: `ftell()` returns a `long`.  Use `printf("%ld", ftell (fp));` and enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: For **-5L** see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17332477/2800918)

Answer (score 1):

-5 means it moves *backwards* five positions from current position (SEEK_CUR).  The "L" is just a numeric modifier to say the -5 is a *long* int type value.

Answer (score 1):

The `fseek(fp, -5L, SEEK_CUR);` directs the file position to move back 5, if possible.

The `L` insures that the *decimal constant* is at least the width of a `long`.

`fseek()` expects an offset of type `long`.

```
int fseek(FILE *stream, long int offset, int whence);
```

The L in `-5L` is not needed here, but no harm either.

---

Note:  `ftell()` returns a `long`, so use `"%ld"`to match the print specifier with the argument type.  Also enable all compiler warnings.

```
// printf("%d", ftell (fp));
printf("%ld", ftell (fp));
```